# Retrive data from mysql database with image in jsp servlet using AJAX on same page

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am working on online shopping website(e-commerce) website, in which I have a task to retrive products (product id, name, imageurl, price, details of product) Image having in image folder folder where stored images and that pah is given to database..
HereI want to fetch category on clicking menu categories without loading whole page needs to display on same page using AJAX.. Is there any solution??.

I don't have any Idea about Ajax and scripting to fetch images using scripting n all.. suggest me how can I resolve my problem using AJAX or JavaScript or jquery???

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a bit of javascript code using the jquery library.

The jquery library will allow you to use ajax to access a special url in your web site to retrieve your category, say yourwebsite/categoryGet

This url's only task is to receive a parameter from the url, query your database accordingly, and return data either in html or in json format.

When your javascript receives the response through a callback function, it can update your page without reload.

This gives you an overview of your task, you should look for examples of using AJAX with jquery. It's not that complicated, really.

For instance, you can follow this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Thanks koriander.. I will go through it.. if you can will you give me one example??